# Executing the wrong Code behind files?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to run very simple code in visual basic but I get the wrong label text coming from other page.

this is the page. for clarity I made a screenshot:

[image]

When I click on the *sport*, for example, a userControl event name "LinkClicked2" Should fire and handle by an event handler and as result shows the text **"Click Detected"**.

but instead I get the text for label of the page of **"MenuHost.aspx"**

***EventForUserControl.aspx:***

```
 <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true"    CodeFile="EventForUserControl.aspx.cs" Inherits="Demo_UserControl_EventForUserControl2" %>

<%@ Register src="LinkMenu.ascx" tagname="LinkMenu" tagprefix="uc1" %>

  <!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<title></title>
</head>
  <body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
 <div>

    <uc1:LinkMenu ID="LinkMenu1" runat="server" OnLinkClicked2="LinkMenu1_OnLinkClicked2" />
    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
</div>
</form>
```

code behind file of EventForUserControl.aspx:

```
  using System;
  using System.Collections.Generic;
  using System.Linq;
  using System.Web;
  using System.Web.UI;
  using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

    public partial class Demo_UserControl_EventForUserControl2 :   System.Web.UI.Page
    {
     protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {

   }

   protected void LinkMenu1_OnLinkClicked2(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    this.Label1.Text = "Click Detected";
    }
 }
```

now instead it shows code behind file of the MenuHost page :

```
using System;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using System.Linq;
 using System.Web;
 using System.Web.UI;
 using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

  public partial class Demo_UserControl_MenuHost : System.Web.UI.Page
   {
     protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    if (Request.Params["Product"] != null)
    {

        this.lblSelection.Text = "You Selected:";
        this.lblSelection.Text += this.Request.Params["Product"];
    }


}
}
```

the **"LinkMenu.ascx"** page :

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="LinkMenu.ascx.cs"   Inherits="Demo_UserControl_LinkMenu" %>
<div>
Products:<br />
<asp:HyperLink id="lnkBooks" runat="server"
NavigateUrl="MenuHost.aspx?product=Books"> Books
</asp:HyperLink> <br />
<asp:HyperLink id="lnkToys" runat="server"
NavigateUrl="MenuHost.aspx?product=Toys"> Toys
</asp:HyperLink> <br />
<asp:HyperLink id="lnkSports" runat="server"
NavigateUrl="MenuHost.aspx?product=Sports"> Sports
</asp:HyperLink> <br />
<asp:HyperLink id="lnkFurniture" runat="server"
NavigateUrl="MenuHost.aspx?product=Furniture"> Furniture
</asp:HyperLink>
</div>
```

Code Behind of the **"LinkMenu.ascx"** page :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class Demo_UserControl_LinkMenu : System.Web.UI.UserControl
 {
public event EventHandler LinkClicked2;

protected void link_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (this.LinkClicked2 != null)
    {
        LinkClicked2(this,EventArgs.Empty);
    }
}
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
}
```

there is no event handler for the LinkMenu.ascx user control event in the codeBehind of MenuHost.

**My question is that why my UserControl event is handled by "MenuHost" page instead of "EventForUserControl" page?**

Comment: Based on your code, when you click on `lnkSports` in LinkMenu.ascx, you are redirecting to `MenuHost.aspx?product=Sports`. Isn't it? Also whenever you perform some event on usercontrol, its code behind would be given the chance to handle it.

Comment: but I made an event for the userControl So if someone clicks on it, it raises and handled by eventHandler on the EventForUserControl.aspx. it logically should ignore by another page. and beside it doesn't direct to another page , it shows a text for a label of MenuHost page.maybe my logic is wrong